# Android: get view from listview by position

Tags: android

i want to change color of listview (simple_list_item_2 adapter) children at specific positions programmatically. (here for example all items with a = lv.getCount();)

```
ListView lv = getListView();
int a = lv.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setTextColor(Color
                    .parseColor("#EEC900"));
}
```

getChildAt(); doesnt always work for me. in case of the list-item being out of sceen, getChild doesnt return a view or something..
isnt there a better solution instead if getChildAt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do this in your Adapter class. Android caches and re-cycles the views in a listview to conserve memory. So there are are no views that you can't see to change the color of.

So for example if you had an arrayAdapter, you would override the getView function and run your check there:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // use "position" to determine which item you have.
        // Then set the properties of "view" which is your list row.

    }
```